# How to change the spacing of the options of a select using CSS only?

Tags: css, dropdown, html-select

I have a dropdown using select/option, but I have a variant that have a span with an icon before the select tag, so I have to add a padding for the select to 'push' the placeholder in order to fit the icon and the text, but when I open the select, the options get that padding too. How to style only the options to remove this padding when I open the dropdown? I tried to add a padding to the option in CSS, but the option attribute doesn't work with padding.

```css
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url("icon.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

select {
  appearance: none;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 32px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <select>
      <option disabled selected hidden>Choose an option</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of the HTML and CSS showing the behavior (termed a [mre] here). More advice available on [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You do not need to add padding on anything. Where do you want the icon to be and is it part of option or just a placeholder for select?

Comment: I want to put an icon before the placeholder, like a span with a svg icon: "Select an option", that's wht the `padding-left:`, but with this padding, the options get that spacing either

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have an `img` that contains your icon and `select` inside a wrapper `div` and remove all border and outline from `select`, so that whole `div` appears like a drop-down. No need for padding. Check the below code snippet.

```css
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.icon {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/500");
  background-size: cover;
}

select {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <img class="icon" />
    <select>
      <option disabled selected hidden>Choose an option</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

The CSS for styling the options to remove the padding when the dropdown is opened can be achieved using the appearance property. By setting appearance: none for the select element and then styling the dropdown arrow separately, you can retain the padding for the select without affecting the options. Here's the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <style>
    .select-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .icon {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 12px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      background-image: url("icon.png");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    select {
      appearance: none;
      padding: 8px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 200px;
      padding-left: 32px; 
    }
    /* Style the dropdown arrow */
    select::-ms-expand {
      display: none;
    }
    select::after {
      content: "\25BC";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 10px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <select>
      <option disabled selected hidden>Choose an option</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to take time to familiarize yourself with the site's rules, including the one that [prohibits the use of "AI" content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).